Missing auto-fix options when extending class with abstract method containing union types?
The class I'm working on has an abstract execute method with type unions. My problem is that when a user of this class imports it for use, there's no auto-fixes available in VS Code, be it add all missing imports or Implement inherited abstract class.
// in ./testType.ts
import { ChatInputCommandInteraction, Message } from 'discord.js';
export abstract class Test<InGuild extends boolean=true> {
    abstract get name(): string;
    abstract execute(type: Message<InGuild> | ChatInputCommandInteraction<'cached'>);
}

// in ./test.ts
import { Test } from './testType';
export class T2 extends Test {
}


The actual error in question:

Non-abstract class 'T2' is missing implementations for the following members of 
'Test<true>': 'name', 'execute'.ts(2654)
class T2
No quick fixes available


Is there something I should be doing with my class definition or is this something not supported by VS Code? Making it easy to adjust to (from an older codebase) is important to me, but as it stands we have to manually import Message and ChatInputCommandInteraction to get any other Quick Fix options.
Edit: After some further testing, it also appears if I make local dummy types to match the definitions from discord.js, the quick fix options are available.
type CacheType = 'cached' | 'raw';
export class Message<T extends boolean=boolean>{ }
export class ChatInputCommandInteraction<T extends CacheType=CacheType>{ }

Edit #2: Attempted to clean up generic arguments for the Test class to pass it through Message instead of using Message directly.
